# Convert current date to Excel timestamp in Power Automate

Tags: excel, datetime, power-automate, office-scripts

In Office Script, I can use Typescript to generate an Excel date using the following code:

```
var seconds = Date.now() / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) + 25569;
```

How do I calculate an Excel timestamp in a Power Automate flow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code can be used to generate an Excel timestamp of the current time in an Power Automate flow:

```
add(div(div(sub(ticks(utcNow()),621355968000000000),10000),86400),25569)
```

UTC time -> ticks -> milliseconds -> Excel time